# How to make my checkbox to be clicked only once and other are unchecked in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component, react-state

I followed a tutorial and created a form with as many checkboxes to be clicked. But, in another case, I need only one box to be checked. The values of checkboxes are dynamic and you never know, how many checkboxes will be created. But, only one can be clicked. Can you please help me in finding the solution thankyou.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Checkbox from "./Checkbox.component";

class PatientSelectTiming extends Component {
state = { 
      options: [...this.props.props],
      checkboxes: [...this.props.props].reduce(
        (options, option) => ({
          ...options,
          [option]: false
        }),
        {}
      ),
      appointmentSlots: null
  };

  handleCheckboxChange = e => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      checkboxes: {
        ...prevState.checkboxes,
        [name]: !prevState.checkboxes[name]
      }
    }))
    }

  handleFormSubmit = formSubmitEvent => {
    formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();
    Object.keys(this.state.checkboxes)
      .filter(checkbox => this.state.checkboxes[checkbox])
      .forEach(checkbox => { 
        let appointmentSlot = [];  
        appointmentSlot.push(checkbox); 
        console.log(appointmentSlot);
        this.setState({appointmentSlots: appointmentSlot})
        localStorage.setItem('appointmentSlots', JSON.stringify(appointmentSlot))     
    });  
  };

  createCheckbox = option => (
    <Checkbox
      label={option}
      isSelected={this.state.checkboxes[option]}
      onCheckboxChange={this.handleCheckboxChange}
      key={option}
    />
  );

  createCheckboxes = () => this.state.options.map(this.createCheckbox);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Only select one item and only first date clicked will be your time</p>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
              {this.createCheckboxes()}
                <button type="submit">
                  Save
                </button>
            </form>
    {this.state.appointmentSlots === null ? <p>Click on any slot to get your time.</p> : <p>Your time is {JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("appointmentSlots"))}</p>}
    </div>
          )
    }
  }
export default PatientSelectTiming;
```

Comment: Use radio buttons with the same name, only one can ever be checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a radio button
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp
Radio button is the same as checkbox but only allows users to check only 1 option.